# How can I change a filetype’s “Kind” value in the Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, customization

There are several filetypes that get a generic “Kind” description (if viewed in Finder’s List View) based on the program used to open them.

I’d like to add descriptions for some file extensions so that they are not of the Kind “[editor] document”.

Is this possible?

If so, how?

Comment: *Why* do you want to change the Kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/path/to/default/app/Contents/Info.plist` → `CFBundleDocumentTypes` → `CFBundleTypeName`:

```
<key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
<array>
    <string>adb</string>
    <string>ads</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
<string>ADA</string>
<key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
<string>ADA source</string>
```

Modifying files inside application bundles invalidates the code signature and changes aren't necessarily respected by updates.

Comment: Interesting…  First of all, thank you for the helpful reply!  Follow-ups: (1) So this data is governed based on the contents of multiple Plist files inside app bundles?!  (2) Is there no central location to accomplish the same goal?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's not really meant to be edited by users. The information about [application-specific services](http://superuser.com/questions/259103/remove-services-on-os-x), [default applications](http://superuser.com/questions/305498/batch-change-default-applications-associated-with-file-types-on-os-x) and icons is kept in `Info.plist`s or inside application bundles as well.